# Cómo obtener en posershell el código de retorno de un request con un objeto internetexplorer.application

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer

Estoy intentando hacer un testeador de links a partir de una página web.
El código simplificado es:

```
$ie = new-object -comobject internetexplorer.application
$ie.navigate($urlInicial)
while ($ie.Busy) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 } 
$ie.Document.links | Foreach-object {
    $link = $_
    $link.click()
}
```

¿Cómo puedo obtener el código (un 404 por ejemplo) del request asociado con el click?
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Sabias que los procesos de IE que ejecutas de esa forma quedan corriendo en el background?...he visto harto codigo similar de personas que vienen de VBA, no es lo mas optimo...

Comment: En mi caso, tengo el ie visible. Si tienes una sugerencia mejor, bienvenida sea.

Comment: En tu caso, yo usaria algo como https://github.com/sergueik/powershell_selenium

Answer (score 0):

El objeto internetexplorer.application no expone el código de retorno de los request, así que no es posible obtenerlo por esta vía.